Is it possible to ask a question in an answer to a question already on the site
I found a question where the user is studying on the same book I'm using, and has asked a question about something on this book, but he asked only "half a question" about it. I'm interested in the other half, can I ask it in the answer? As a new question would be almost a duplicate of the one already on the site.

Not sure I follow.  If the original question is incomplete, missing half of the problem you are interested in, then a new question on the other half would not be a duplicate.

No.
Questions go in question posts. You can include a link to the original to provide additional context.
Questions do not go in answer posts. You should only ever use them for answering the question. Not for commentary, not for extending discussion, not for tacking on a follow-up query.

Also not for ordering pizza.
